# Error using CArray: cannot access private member declared in class CObject

Tags: c++, mfc

I've created a dll using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and all works fine; now I want to add a member variable to the class I export; this member variable is a vector of struct which contains a CArray of another struct. The error I have in debug mode is

> ```
> error C2248: 'CObject::CObject': cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtempl.h  262
> ```

I know I get this error because there a problem with the constructor of the struct which contains the CArray but I'm not able to fix it. Please help me.
Below I posted the code.

EXPORTED CLASS:

```
namespace optFun
{
    // si posso definire altri casi in base a dove vengono collocati gli strumenti di gestione delle eccezioni
    enum RETURN{
        RETURN_INIT=0,
        RETURN_ERRORINREADING,
        RETURN_ERRORINPARALLEL,
        RETURN_ERRORINMAKESPAN,
        RETURN_SUCCESSFUL
    };

    struct DataPrescription{
    EDrug  NameDrug;
    float Dosage;
    EContainerType DestType;
    ELiquid IdDest;
    float CapacityDest;
    float Priority;
    bool ScaricoShaker;
    int  BlockNumber;

    DataPrescription(){
        NameDrug=EDrug_NoDrug;
        Dosage=0.0;
        DestType= EContainerType_Tot;
        IdDest=ELiquid_NoLiquid;
        CapacityDest=0.0;
        Priority=0.0;
        ScaricoShaker=true;
        BlockNumber=0;
    }

    DataPrescription(EDrug name,float dos,EContainerType dest,ELiquid ID,float cap_dest,float p,bool _ScaricoShaker,int _BlockNumber){
        NameDrug=name;
        Dosage=dos;
        DestType=dest;
        IdDest=ID;
        CapacityDest=cap_dest;
        Priority=p;
        ScaricoShaker=_ScaricoShaker;
        BlockNumber=_BlockNumber;
    }
};

struct final_block{

  CArray<DataPrescription> block_list;
  vector<load_info> carico;
  bool scarico_MI;
  final_block(){
      scarico_MI=false;
  }
};
    // This class is exported from the optFunDll.dll
    class OPTFUNDLL_API OptimizationTool
    {
    public: 
        // funzione che implementa il modulo di ottimizzazione
        CArray<DataPrescription> OptList;
        time_info time;
        vector<final_block> execution_mode;
        vector<state_info> StatusInfo;
        vector<load_info> LoadIndication;
        CArray<DataPrescription> ShakingList; //lista dei soli farmaci da restituire nell'ordine ottimo di schedulazione

        OptimizationTool(void);
        ~OptimizationTool();

        void CreateDataPrescription(vector<block>&);
        //void CreateBlockPrescription(block&); 
        RETURN scheduling(vector<string>,const char*,const char*,const char*);
        void InitializeParameter(double,int);
        void LoadDetails(vector<block>&,vector<magazzino_ospedale>&);
        //void ToLoad(ricetta&,vector<magazzino_ospedale>&,vector<magazzino_ospedale>&);
        void SyncronizeLoad(vector<block>&);

        // accessor function
        double get_PercVel();
        int get_CountSame();


    private:
        double _PercentMaximumVelocityOfSearchSpace; // % che determina range di variazione della velocità (e quindi anche della posizione)
        int _CountSame; // numero di stesse iterazioni dopo le quali la procedura di ottimizzazione si arresta


    };
}
```

The struct which give me error is "final_block"; I used this struct in this way:

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<output.size();i++){
           final_block pr;
           for(unsigned int j=0;j<output[i].list.size();j++){
               DataPrescription tmp(output[i].list[j].getID(),output[i].list[j].getdosage(),output[i].list[j].get_destination(),output[i].list[j].get_DestType(),output[i].list[j].get_CapacityDest(),output[i].list[j].getPriority(),output[i].list[j].processing_info.scarico_shaker,i+1);
               pr.block_list.Add(tmp);
           }
           pr.carico.push_back(this->LoadIndication[i]);
           pr.scarico_MI=output[i].scarico_MI;
          this->execution_mode.push_back(pr);
       }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you using both vector and CArray?  Why not just vector?

Comment: i'm forced to use a CArray in this case because it's a project specification; this dll is called inside a software which uses MFC containers.

Comment: Can you please point to the exact line where the error occurs? Also, that is a weird project specification -- sometimes use CArray, other times use vector. Sounds like someone couldn't make up their mind as to what to use.  Your explanation doesn't sound convincing -- you can use vector's in MFC projects and programs with no issues.

Comment: Well, looks like you need to revise your project specfications -- you now have to recode to either use a vector (much easier), or make CArray copyable (more risky). Unless there is something in CObject that you cannot do without, there is absolutely no issue in using vector instead of CArray in an MFC program.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that MFC `CArray` (which derives from `CObject`) is **not copyable**.

So, the `CArray` data member inside your `final_block` structure makes the latter not copyable as well.

So, being not copyable, you can't `push_back()` instances of `final_block` in a `std::vector`.

An option is to just substitute `CArray` with **`std::vector` in your `final_block` structure.

Or you can provide custom copy constructor and copy assignment for your `final_block` structure, and writing custom code for copying the `CArray` member.

Frankly, I'd just use `std::vector` instead of `CArray`.

Comment: Yes, the old CObject issue.I agree about using vector instead of CArray. In this day and age, what does CArray gives you except a headache trying to use it in many circumstances.